# Nan in summary histogram for: model/Training/dense/kernel/gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm building a dataset with 45 features, all numerical, and normalized so values gets between -1 and 1.

Here is the normalization:

```
def normalize(train, test, cv):
    normalized_train=(train-train.mean())/train.std()
    normalized_test=(test-test.mean())/test.std()
    normalized_cv=(cv-cv.mean())/cv.std()
    return normalized_train, normalized_test, normalized_cv
X_train, X_test, X_cv = normalize(X_train, X_test, X_cv)
```

Then I am building the tensorflow dataset and iterator and pass it to my model.
Here is the model:

```
with tf.name_scope('model'):
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1)
net = tf.layers.dense(features, 40, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer, 
                        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())                        
net = tf.layers.dense(net, 60, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
net = tf.layers.dense(net, 30, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
net = tf.layers.dense(net, 12, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
                        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
prediction = tf.layers.dense(net, 2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
```

And finally my loss function, my optimizer and the gradient calculation then applied:

```
with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=labels, logits=prediction) 
    tf.summary.scalar('Loss', loss)
with tf.name_scope('Training'):
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
    grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
    for grad, var in grads:
        if grad is not None:
            tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name + '/gradients', grad)
    train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Caused by op 'model/Training/dense/kernel/gradients', defined at:
  File "c:\Users\123456\Google Drive\Projects\GIT\Churn_TF\churn_1.2_local_dataset.py", line 103, in <module>
    tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name + '/gradients', grad)
  File "C:\Users\123456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py", line 193, in histogram
    tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)
  File "C:\Users\123456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py", line 215, in _histogram_summary
    "HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\123456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\123456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\123456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary histogram for: model/Training/dense/kernel/gradients
         [[Node: model/Training/dense/kernel/gradients = HistogramSummary[T=DT_DOUBLE, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](model/Training/dense/kernel/gradients/tag, model/Training/gradients/model/dense/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_101)]]
```

Problem is  `Nan in summary histogram for: model/Training/dense/kernel/gradients`

From what I read it could be an exploding gradient issue, but how can I debug this since the point of creating these histogram was to see what happens with my gradients?

Also since I normalized and regularized I am surprised to get this.... could be that my gradients become too small?

I have tried to replace `tf.nn.relu` by `tf.nn.leaky_relu` but then I get a float64 to float32 conversion error that I don't manage to fix.... any idea to help me fixing this ?

Answer (score 1):

From your code

```
prediction = tf.layers.dense(net, 2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
```

I infer that you have a two class classification problem and the activation function of your output layer is the sigmoid function.

However, as your loss function you are using the

```
tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy
```

function. So first of all I would suggest to use the

```
tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy
```

function. Note that this function (and also the tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy function) expects the (unscaled) logits as an input. So in your case, the result of your final layer **before** applying the sigmoid non-linearity. Hence, I would recommend to change the following line

```
prediction = tf.layers.dense(net, 2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
```

to

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(net, 2)
prediction = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits) # this line is only needed if you want to use predictions somewhere else
```

and then

```
loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=labels, logits=logits)
```

Maybe this already solves your problem. If not, what learning rate are you using? I usually get this error if the learning rate is too large.

Comment: That was definitely a glitch but unfortunately not the issue. The learning rate is quite small: 0.00005, I have tried to have higher or smaller values by a 10^2 factor but same issue. I have tried to add a small numerical value to the loss but still the same issue.

Comment: what are your labels? 0 and 1?

Comment: Ok. So if you remove the histogram summary, what happens to your loss during training?

Comment: My loss decreases